# Установка игрового сервера на локальный компьютер

Tags: linux, debian, minecraft, vmware

На VMware установлена виртуальная машина Debian 12 server (без графического отображения, только консоль).

На неё был установлен openssh для подключения к SSH / SFTP. Через "ip a", я посмотрел IP-адрес для подключения и смог выполнить вход в SSH и SFTP, загрузил данные игрового сервера Minecraft Pocket Edition который по конфигурации должен использовать 19132 порт по протоколу UDP.
[image: вывел все ip адрес, по 192.168.241.142 я смог зайти в ssh и sftp]

Дальше я запустил сервер, он включился, но зайти через Minecraft Client я не смог.

Решил проверить 19132 порт открыт или закрыт, через Nmap увидел, что он открыт.
[image: информация об открытом порте]

После чего решил проверить порт на check-host.net, он также работает.
[image: информация с check-host.net]

Но, почему-то всеровно не работает вход на сервер.
Буду очень благодарен, если напишите какие-то советы / рекомендации по решению этой проблемы.

Comment: Эээ, ты вбил в сайт по проверке доступности локальный адрес и тебе показали, что всё ок? И тебя ничего не смутило?

Comment: А что меня должно было смутить? Буду благодарен, если объяснишь

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C#%D0%90%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F